# ElementAPI: Error's out if entry doesn't have assets

Tags: entries, assets, plugin-elementapi

These keeps erroring out if any of the entries' do not have any assets in the 'listingPhotos' field. However, IF all entries have at least 1 photo in the 'listingsPhotos' field, it works.

The Error Message: Trying to get property of non-object

```
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'trucks.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => ['section' => 'trucks'],
            'paginate' => false,
            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
                return [
                    'ID' => $entry->id,
                    'Year' => $entry->year,
                    'Manufacturer' => $entry->manufacturer,
                    'Model' => $entry->model,
                    'Category' => (string)$entry->category[0],
                    'Pics' => $entry->listingPhotos[0]->url,
                ];
            },
        ],
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just check if there is at least one photo? Something along the lines of

```
'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
    return [
        'ID' => $entry->id,
        'Year' => $entry->year,
        'Manufacturer' => $entry->manufacturer,
        'Model' => $entry->model,
        'Category' => (string)$entry->category[0],
        'Pics' => !empty($entry->listingPhotos) ? $entry->listingPhotos[0]->url : null,
    ];
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this earlier but it didn't work. I was able to get your code to work, but I had to add [0]-> to the argument:
`'Pics' => !empty($entry->listingPhotos[0]->url) ? $entry->listingPhotos[0]->url : null,`